# NSubstitute not responding to Received() assertation

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I have a test which mocks a non-interface object with a constructor that takes parameters:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var myObject = Substitute.For<MyObject>("param1", "param2");

        _sut.DoSomething(myObject);

        myObject.Received().SomeMethodWhichIsCalled();
    }
```

This passes and when I debug the test, I can see `SomeMethodWhichIsCalled()` on `MyObject` is executed correctly.

However I've now realised this assert does nothing, because I can add the below in:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var myObject = Substitute.For<MyObject>("param1", "param2");

        _sut.DoSomething(myObject);

        myObject.DidNotReceive().SomeMethodWhichIsCalled();
        myObject.Received().SomeMethodWhichIsCalled();
    }
```

And the test still passes...

Is this a side effect of mocking classes and not interfaces?

Comment: Be aware that you can mock only virtual members.

Comment: Try the [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute.Analyzers.CSharp/) package. It should help by detecting attempts to mock non-virtual members.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock only virtual members. The mocking-framework simply overrides the virtual members for you similar to this:

```
class MyMock : MyObject
{
    override void SomeMethodWhichIsCalled()
    {
        throw new Exception("Method was called");
    }
}
```

As your method is not `virtual` the framework isn´t able to override it and thus the actual method `SomeMethodWhichIsCalled` of `MyObject` is called, which never throws the exception.

There´s not much you can do about this, unless you can make the method `virtual`. You could try to access some internal state via reflection, but that highly depends on what `SomeMethodWhichIsCalled` does. In particular it´s only a dirty hack.